# Como asignar dinámicamente el valor a una variable de un formulario en APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

Estoy creando una aplicación y en un momento dado tengo un formulario. La mayoría de las entradas son introducidas por el usuario. Sin embargo, hay 1 variable a las que quiero asignar el valor una vez el usuario haya introducido cierta información.

Para poner en contexto, mi aplicación es una página de ventas, y el formulario en cuestión es el de añadir pedido. En él, el usuario debe elegir la cantidad del objeto y el propio objeto a comprar (esto devuelve el ID del objeto). Entonces, una nueva variable a la que he llamado "Precio por unidad" tomará el valor "precio" de la tabla "pedidos" en función del objeto que el usuario ha elegido. La función dinámica que he agregado a esta variable es esta:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.PRICE
   FROM PRODUCTS
   WHERE PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID = :P12_PRODUCT
```

Teniendo en cuenta que P12_Product es el ID del producto seleccionado como comenté anteriormente. Sin embargo, no funciona, ya que aún seleccionando el objeto, no muestra ningún valor. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar acciones dinámicas para que dependiendo del producto seleccionado se cargue el precio unitario y haga el cálculo de acuerdo al número de unidades.

A continuación los pasos:

1. Crear una acción dinámica, que se active cuando se seleccione el producto.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Crear una acción que ejecute código PL/SQL, incluir una sección de excepciones por si el producto no se encuentra y también incluir el cálculo total := precio * cantidad (por ejemplo).

Tener en cuenta los elementos para enviar y retornar.
El valor que ingresa es el id del producto (P3_PRODUCTO) y el que retorna es el precio (P3_PRECIO).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]